# Can miners "lie" about how much gas a computation cost them?

Tags: gas, miner

I've noticed that I'm hardly refunded gas fees. Why is this? Are miners somehow lying about how much gas a computation cost? Can they lie? How is this prevented?

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot.

They can try, but the validators also run the contract and they will arrive at the same deterministic result.